# How to access selenium rotation= from capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am trying to access the rotation= definition and my IDE (RubyMine) does show it has the correct path there with this line and I can read the rotatable.rb file that it lives in.

```
page.driver.browser.rotation = :portrait
```

I also tried

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.rotation = :portrait
```

But when it runs I get this error

```
undefined method `rotation=' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x00007fc80a90b210> (NoMethodError)
```

I have checked the docs here, as well. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/DriverExtensions/Rotatable

Any advice on what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only driver the `Rotatable` module is included into is the remote driver (Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Driver) - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/driver.rb#L31 - so that's the only one the `rotation=` method is supported in.  You are using the local chrome driver (Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver) where the method is not supported/implemented.